# Behavior of ngModel vs formControlName for radio elements

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngmodel, form-control, angular-template-form

While working with validating same radio input elements with two different approaches viz. template-driven-form and model-driven-form, I am stuck with the scenario where for template-driven-form, using `ngModel`, I get single instance of control for 3 radio elements but for model-driven-form, using `formControlName`, I get 3 separate instances.

```html
<!-- template-driven-form.component.html -->
<div class="form-group gender">
  <label for="gender">Select Gender:</label>
  <div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" [value]="gender" ngModel appFormControlValidation validationMsgId="gender" required />
    <label>{{ gender }}</label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- model-driven-form.component.html -->
<div class="form-group gender">
  <label for="gender">Select Gender:</label>
  <div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" [value]="gender" formControlName="gender" appFormControlValidation validationMsgId="gender" required />
    <label>{{ gender }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
// model-driven-form.component.ts
genders: string[] = ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'];
this.modelForm = new FormGroup({
  gender: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
});

// template-driven-form.component.ts
genders: string[] = ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'];

// form-control-directive
(this.control as NgControl).statusChanges.subscribe(
  // returns single instance for 3 radio elements -> template form
  // returns 3 instance for 3 radio elements -> model form
);
```

As from snippet above, I am using same HTML structure for both forms yet number instances vary. Problem here is when the validation happens, for template-driven-form, I get error message only once (which is expected scenario) but for model-driven-form, I get error messages displayed 3 times!

[image: VALIDATION_SCENARIO]

My question is:

1. Why is number of instance generated for same element type different for `ngModel` and `formControlName`?
2. What changes are required so that `formControlName` also returns single instance?

Working [Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cvwyru?file=src/app/app.component.ts) version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @AndreiGatej - https://github.com/indepth-dev/community/discussions/53

*Description*:
After a quick investigation, it is actually expected to get three instances. Concretely, the `statusChanges` from `this.statusChangeSubscription = this.control?.statusChanges?.subscribe()` is subscribed 3 times. If you have `N` radio buttons, then you'll end up with `N` instances of that directive. This implies that although you're having `N` instances, they will all inject **the same** `NgControl` instance(which can be `NgModel`, `FormControlName` and `FormControlDirective`). And that `NgControl` instance is, in the case of reactive forms, this one:

```js
gender: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
```

The reason this doesn't apparently happen when using `NgModel` is that when using Template-Driven forms, the form control directives are created on the fly. This is the flow that sets up an `NgModel` directive:

1. [`this.formDirective.addControl(this)`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L268).
2. The `NgModel`'s `NgControl` is added in the Form Directives Tree at the end of [this tick](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L188). The reason for that can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L29-L45).
3. The interesting part is that although each `NgModel` directive [inherently creates a unique `FormControl` instance](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L139), in the directives tree there will be only one `FormControl` instance which will be shared by all the `NgModel` which share the [same name](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L165). [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1555) is the piece of logic which indicates that a single `FormControl` instance will be shared:

```js
if (this.controls[name]) return this.controls[name];
   this.controls[name] = control;
   control.setParent(this);
   control._registerOnCollectionChange(this._onCollectionChange);
   return control;
```

`registerControl` is called after the `resolvedPromise` promise has been resolved. It's also there where `dir.control` is assigned to whatever `registerControl` returns.

So, the directive's `ngOnInit` is called **before** that promise(which is essentially `Promise.resolve()`) resolves. At the end of the current tick, all the NgModel directives will share the same `FormControl` instance. This is why it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I founded a solution that is to check if yet there're a app-error before adding, see the `if (parent.innerHTML.indexOf(componentFactory.selector) < 0)` in your dynamic-component.service

```
  loadComponentIntoNode(
    vcr: ViewContainerRef,
    dynamicItem: DynamicItem,
    parentNode = null
  ): void {
    if (dynamicItem.component) {
      const parent = parentNode || vcr.element.nativeElement;
      const componentFactory =
        this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
          dynamicItem.component
        );
      if (parent.innerHTML.indexOf(componentFactory.selector) < 0) {
        const componentRef = vcr.createComponent(componentFactory);
        const newChild =
          componentRef.injector.get(ErrorComponent).elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.renderer.appendChild(parent, newChild);
        (componentRef.instance as DynamicComponent).data = dynamicItem.data;
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is, if you check the statusChange that, in a template driven form has as Observers an array of so many elements you has in radio, and an array of one element in model drive forms, But I can not find a solution about this

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo for taking time to work on this. I was already aware of this alternate solution (a.k.a. "hack") to prevent duplication, however, we both know that this is not optimal! My sole purpose to open this thread was to understand the core reason behind such behavior and fill-in the knowledge gap that I have now. Thanks again!

Comment: if in your `form-control.validation.directive- in ngOnInit, before subscribe you write `(this.control.statusChanges as any).observers=[]`  (a console.log(this.control.statusChanges) you see that "observers" is an array, at first empty, after with one elements and after with two element) also only dispach one time the error, but really I don't know if is a "really hack" or can crash the app (really I think is time to ask to the guys of Angular).

Comment: Thanks for debugging further. This is really frustrating for me Eliseo, working on this for 3 days and no lead & as you mentioned to reach out to official people, I've already contacted two GDE's on twitter, let's see how this goes. Thanks for your time Eliseo, really appreciate that man!

Comment: I imagine that all the problem goes from the _initObservables function (call in  FormControl constructor), see the [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts) a simple "if" should resolve the problem but it's outside my knowledge. BTW, sometime ago -sorry if this suppose a little deception about you great work- Netanet Basal wrote an article ["Make your angular forms errors message magically apear"](https://netbasal.com/make-your-angular-forms-error-messages-magically-appear-1e32350b7fa5). -he use valueChanges, not status change

Comment: He is a great guy, my mentor. I thoroughly follow all his articles along with others from indepth-dev. Learnt a lot from these 2 sources. My requirement was bit more specific and hence I was not able to use his solution as is but the idea of using dynamic component to display error message is surely from the link that you've provided!